# Leaflet polygon highlight issue

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I followed the leaflet tutorial here https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ that explains how to highlight the borders of the polygons during mouseover and mouseout. However, on my map the polygon only highlights when the cursor is over the polygon line and not when the cursor is inside the area of the polygon like in the tutorial. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**JS Code Snippet:**

```
// highlight county borders
function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
}

// reset county borders highlight
function resetHighlight(e) {
    borderLayer.resetStyle(e.target);
}

// zooms to selected feature
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature,
    });
}

// loads county borders from geojson
var borderLayer = L.geoJSON(countyBorders, {
    style: borderStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
});
```

Comment: You can try the Turf library: http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointInPolygon but you for the turf functions you have to use geojson data, means latlng swapped to lnglat

Comment: I wonder if the geojson dataset is polygons or just lines? :-|

Comment: The geojson dataset is type "polygon". I'll try this in a new leaflet map and see if I'm getting the same result.

Comment: I think you should provide a full [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (consider www.leafletjs.com/edit)